# DocuSign Rest API v2.1 OpenAPI specification swagger file

Tags: docusignapi

Spec for API v2  is currently hosted at [eSign-OpenAPI-Specification](https://github.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification).

If v2.1 will be available, then will it continue to use the swagger version or version 3 of `OpenAPI`?

Answer (score 0):

(I work for DocuSign.)

Initially, DocuSign Rest API v2.1 Swagger file will be published as a Swagger file. We don't yet have a plan to update the Swagger file format to the v3 OpenAPI format.

What will you do with the Swagger file? Please update your question or comment on this answer. Thanks.

### 2019.07.14 Update

Updating the [GitHub Swagger repo](https://github.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification) with the v2.1 spec is now planned for an upcoming sprint. Please contact DocuSign customer support and ask them to add your name and company information to internal tickets DCM-3387 and DCM-3388.

Comment: I generate the go packages in  [github.com/jfcote87/esign](https://github.com/jfcote87/esign) using the Swagger definition and am planning to add v2.1.

Comment: any word on when the version 2.1 swagger file will be released?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger file specification for our  v2.1 API was published today. you can find it here - https://github.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification